# what is the difference between rownames(y[33,]) and rownames(y)[33]?

Tags: r

Let's do rbind on data of mtcars.

```
apply(mtcars,2,sum)->x
rbind(mtcars,x)
rbind(mtcars,x)->y
```

Why `rownames(y[33,])<-"total"` can not change the name of y[33,]?
Why `rownames(y)[33]<-"total"` can change the name of y[33,]?
What is the difference between them?

```
> y[33,]
     mpg cyl   disp   hp   drat      wt   qsec vs am gear carb
33 642.9 198 7383.1 4694 115.09 102.952 571.16 14 13  118   90
> rownames(y[33,])
[1] "33"
> class(y[33,])
[1] "data.frame"
```

y[33,] is not a vector ,is a data.frame,it has rownames too.

Comment: y[33,] returns a data frame not a vector. While sub-setting one column from a data frame returns a vector; sub-setting one row returns a data frame.

Comment: @MarktheGraph You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subset a data frame to get one row (y[33,]), it creates a new (one row) data frame.

However, as this sub-setting occurred in side a function call, the newly created one row data frame was not assigned to a variable. This makes it hard to subsequently inspect that one row data frame.

Believe it or not, you successfully changed the name of the one row in that data frame to 'total'.

You can check this by going z <- rownames(y[33,]) <- 'total'; print(z). When z is printed we have one row name with the value 'total' (from the one row data frame created when the expression y[33,] was evaluated inside the call to the rownames function).

However, as I noted above, because the newly created data frame was not assigned to a variable; your capacity to subsequently inspect that data frame was lost. Because it is not assigned to any variable, it will ultimately be cleaned up by the R garbage collector.

On the other hand, rownames(y) yields all 33 row names from the data frame assigned to y. The row names are in a vector. Using the numeric index 33 and the assignment, ensures that the desired row name is changed. Because the data frame object is assigned to the variable y; you can inspect it afterwards to see that the change has taken place.

Hope this helps explain what is going on with your two expressions that look similar, but which are actually very different.